# Algorithm - Find all sets that satisfy any combination of the input elements

Tags: algorithm, set

Assuming we have an input which is a list of elements:

{a , b , c , d , e , f}

There are also different sets which may contain any combination of those elements and may also contain other elements that are not in the input list:

A:{e,f} B:{d,f,a} C:{g,a,b} D:{a,h,k}

The algorithm should return only sets A and B.

At first glance I thought about sorting the input list and looping through all the sets checking if each element inside the set exists in the input list. In my case though the input list will be small but the number of sets would be huge so I wouldn't want to loop through all the sets except once. The inputs will often change but the sets will not.

Comment: If your input elements have a limited amount of possibilities (e.g. 'a'-'z'), the usual way is to represent a set as a number where a single bit represents a single  value in the set...a 1 for 'element present' and a 0 for not present. Then you can use basic binary operations (and, or, xor, ...) to quickly check if a set is a result set or not.

Comment: Indeed the number of possibilities is limited. I think my last sentence is very badly written what I meant is that this algorithm is expected to run a couple of times each minute with either a new input list or a modified one based of the previous one. I will try to code your solution tomorrow and see how fitting it is for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the (limited!) alphabet of the input set to a bit set and then use binary operations to test whether or not another set is a (complete) subset of the reference set.

Here a sample implementation:

```ml
type CharSet = string
type EncodedCharSet = uint32

let encode (set : CharSet) : EncodedCharSet =
    set.ToCharArray()
    |> Array.fold (fun a c -> a ||| (1u <<< (int c - int 'a')) ) 0u

let inSet (reference : EncodedCharSet) (test : EncodedCharSet) : bool =
    0u = (reference &&& test) ^^^ test

let test a b =
    let (ae,be) = (encode a, encode b)
    inSet ae be

[
    "ef"
    "dfa"
    "gab"
    "ahk"
]
|> List.map (test "abcdef")
```